# raw.plot() not plotting time series in eeg data

Tags: mne-python

I am using mne to read my EEG data. When I am doing raw.plot(), I am getting an image of this type, rather than a time series.   I am unable to interpret this. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see here: https://mne.discourse.group/t/plotting-eeg-data-too-big-and-scroll-does-not-work/2533. Had the same problem, and doing **scalings='auto'** actually helped. Hope it helps you too:)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).